# Truncate file affect the read process

Tags: c, linux

Recently, I am reading the UNIX Systems Programming, and doing some test.
I'm confused that why i truncate the file with truncate command in the terminal, then the read process read the same position return 0 which return the string "a" before. The process open the file, it will cache the file, beacase i change the file content, then read, the result is the same not changed, so why truncate file will affect the process immediately？In the UNIX Systems Programming, it says that v node include the current file size? so the size don't be read from the disk every time, it's cached in the memory.

the read process code source.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("a.txt", O_RDONLY);
    char buf[1024];
    int n;
    for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        if (lseek(fd, 0, 0) == -1){
            return 1;
        }
        n = read(fd, buf, 1);
        if (n < 0){
            perror("error");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%d\n", n);
        buf[n]=0;
        printf("buf %s\n", buf);
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a.txt only have one char:

```
a
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to show the code you're using.  If you use the system calls (`read()`, `write()`, `truncate()`, `open()`, etc) rather than the standard I/O library calls (`fread()`, `getc()`, `fopen()`, etc), you should see the truncation by a separate process take effect immediately.  If your first program (the non-truncating one) had a read position at 1024 bytes, but the file is truncated, the next read will return 0 (indicating EOF).  Standard I/O library has buffering; it might not spot the truncation immediately. Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) that shows what puzzles you.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for debug verbal problem descriptions,
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler,  shellter, sorry, I have completed the code, I'm confused why truncate file will affect the read process immediately? the file size is cached, it will not read the size from the disk immediately every time, why the read process know the file size have been changed? so is it that the kernel notify the process which open the file?

Comment: pluse-uno for including some code, but you may just have to accept "that's the way it works". In many cases such problems, viewed from another prespectve can be construed as features. (seriously!) . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter, OK, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Caching is usually intended to improve performance, without having any other detectable effects.

If the inode was cached by the process, as you describe, then modifications made by another process might not be visible by processes that had cached information. That would be bad.

In reality, disk blocks are cached, inodes are cached, various other structures might be cached, but in each case there is a single cache, in the kernel, which all processes share, so they all have a consistent view.

When one process truncates the file, the in-memory cache is updated, storing the new file size (which will eventually be written to disk, but probably not immediately). When the other process calls `read` again, the updated file size is read from the in-memory cache, not from disk.

Comment: Thank you for your replying, but every process cache its own inode, if they share the same inode, one process change the file content, the other will be visible. advanced programming in the unix environment also have the graph. just like this ![link](http://ozm96jz5v.bkt.clouddn.com/1511666617.png?imageMogr2/thumbnail/!70p)

Comment: All the stuff in your diagram is in kernel memory. The "process table entry" is a structure in the kernel representing what the kernel knows about a process. It contains pointers to entries in the open file table, which contains pointers to inodes (I don't know about this vnode stuff... it's BSD terminology, doesn't apply to Linux). There can be multiple pointers pointing at the same thing from different processes. There will never be more than one copy of the same inode in memory at one time.

Comment: If  the kernel only have one copy of the same inode in memory, why I modify the file content and then wq with vim in the terminal, the read process can't read the changed?

Comment: sorry, @Wumpus Q. Wumbley, I confuse the inode and data block, so the data block may be cached more than one copy in the kernel?

Comment: I got it, vim doesn't write the file dirently,                            1. write buffer to new file
2. delete the original file
3. rename the new file

Comment: Please accept the answer that best solves your problem, if any, by pressing the [checkmark sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) . This gives the respondent with the best answer 15 points of reputation. It is not subtracted (as some people seem to think) from the original-posters reputation points ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @jacky: Note: Steps 2 and 3 are usually the same step (the `rename` system call can rename the new file to match the name of the old file as a single step, with the old file being deleted by side-effect, though the old data may still exist if other hardlinks or open handles to it exist), so the update to the file is atomic; even if the plug is pulled unpredictably, you'd end up with *either* the original contents *or* the new contents, not an incomplete/corrupt/mixed view of the data.